# How to capture substring/word having a certain pattern from a string in perl?

Tags: perl

```
open(LOGFILE,"<sim_success.log") or die("could not open file");
while (<LOGFILE>){
$line = $_;
chomp($line);
my @design = grep (/Design:/, $line);
push (@final, @design);
}
print $final[0];

close LOGFILE;
```

> Design: D:\Test\Example\Example1_wrk....

How to save "Example_wrk" in a var in perl?

Comment: If we print $final[1]> Only change is it becomes ...Example2_wrk, need to save that in var

Comment: So you have stored all the lines matching "Design:" in the array `@final`. That is a variable. Job done? The question seems not to capture what you actually are trying to do.

Comment: So you want to take the path out of the line?

Comment: Use lexical variables, not bareword filehandles. Barewords are effectively global. They're not first-class values; you can't easily store them in variables, pass them to functions, etc. They're unchecked: The compiler doesn't provide any typo protection for them. Lexical variables follow normal scoping rules. They even automatically close themselves when they go out of scope.

Comment: Use 3-arg open, not 2-arg open. 2-arg open applies extra parsing to the second argument in order to pick out the open mode and filename. This can lead to problems with user input or if your filename actually starts/ends with whitespace. The 3-argument form of open avoids all of this by just passing the two values (mode, filename) in two separate arguments.

Comment: Include the filename and the failure reason in the error message. As a user, I would find a message like `could not open file at whatever.pl line 264` unhelpful. You can get the failure reason from `$!` (corresponds to `strerror(errno)` in C).

Comment: Don't use global variables for no reason. E.g. `$line` is only used within the loop. There is no reason for it to be a global variable.

Comment: Always start your Perl files with `use strict; use warnings;`. This diagnoses many common problems (including detecting typos in variable names at compile time).

Comment: @melpomene you forgot the part where `$line is obsolete`, or should be used in the head. Oh but then you were not done yet. :)

Comment: Don't overwrite `$_` if you want to store the line in `$line` anyway. Why assign to `$_`, then copy to `$line` if you can just assign to `$line` in the first place? `while (my $line = <$logfh>) {`

Comment: Don't use `grep` on a single value. `grep` filters a list according to a certain predicate, but in this case you just want to either add `$line` to `@final` or not. This can be simply written as `push @final, $line if $line =~ /Design:/;`

Comment: It looks like you only care about the first element of `@final`. In that case, why use an array at all? `my $final; while (my $line = readline $fh) { chomp $line; if ($line =~ /Design:/) { $final = $line; last; } } print $final, "\n";`

Comment: That said, I don't see what that code has to do with your question. The answer to your question is `$var = "Example_wrk";`.

Comment: Which relates back to my first comment ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess. I think what you want is to capture the filename from that line of log file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @final;
open my $fh, '<', 'sim_success.log' or die "could not open file: $!";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ m/Design: (.+)$/ ) { 
        push @final, $1;
    }
}
print $final[0]; # will print only the first one
close $fh;
```

Let's see what I did. A lot of this has been explained in melpomene's comments on the question already. I'll reiterate some of them.

- always `use strict` and `use warnings`! They help you to spot errors.
- `grep` does not do what you think. It's for finding things in a list that match a condition. Your list only had one item. The line.
- you can use the `m//` operator directly.
- but you need a capture group `()`, that captures everything
- and the captured stuff will be in `$1`, which we can `push` to the array

When the program is done, the array `@final` might contain one or more matches. If more than one line matches, there are more entries in the array.